# Trying to call IronPython from VB.net -- "Name 'PythonEngine' is not declared."

Tags: vb.net, ironpython

I am trying to replicate [this example of calling IronPython](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/08/14/calling-ironpython-functions-from-net.aspx) code from VB.net.  I've downloaded and installed [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=IronPython) and created a VB.net console application.  I added references to all of the dlls in the IronPython installation folder:

- IronPython
- IronPython.Modules
- IronPythonTest
- Microsoft.Scripting.ExtensionAttribute
- Microsoft.Scripting
- Microsoft.Scripting.Core

And I have this source code:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting
Imports Microsoft.Scripting
Imports IronPython.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Runtime.Types

Module Module1
    Public Class HelloWorldVB
        Public Overridable Function HelloWorld(ByVal name As String) As String
            Return String.Format("Hello '{0}' from Visual Basic", name)
        End Function
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim helloWorld As New HelloWorldVB()
        Console.WriteLine(helloWorld.HelloWorld("Maurice"))

        Dim runtime As ScriptRuntime = PythonEngine.CurrentEngine.Runtime
        Dim scope As ScriptScope = Runtime.ExecuteFile("HelloWorld.py")
        Dim pythonType As PythonType = scope.GetVariable(Of PythonType)("HelloWorldIronPython")
        helloWorld = CType(Runtime.Operations.Call(pythonType), HelloWorldVB)
        Console.WriteLine(helloWorld.HelloWorld("Maurice"))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

I receive the error "Name 'PythonEngine' is not declared."

I can't seem to find PythonEngine when I search the ObjectBrowser.

Is the example out of date or do I have an error?

Answer (score 0):

Things seem to have changed.

I have not worked on IronPython & have downloaded it now.
I tried relating your code with what is inside IronPython.DLL

- Add reference to IronPython.dll
- Add statement for imports - "Imports IronPython.Hosting".

`Dim scriptEngine as Python.CreateEngine()

    Dim scope As ScriptScope = scriptEngine.ExecuteFile("myfile.py")`

I guess rest of your code should work as it is.
Load the Ironpython.dll into reflector & you will be able to see the types/methods/properties.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link in the FAQ that came with IronPython 2.0.1 have you read through it before?
[Aaron Marten : A bit more on IronPython](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronmar/archive/2006/02/16/533273.aspx)